# How do I make a member visible to its subclasses (which might not be in the same package)?

Tags: java

I have an abstract base class with certain fields/abstract methods in it.

How do I make these visible to its children, even if the children don't live in the same package? (And I think `public` is a bit too open, where `protected` would not work!)

(To the comments below, `protected` DOES NOT work because `protected` fields are ONLY VISIBLE WITHIN the same package)

To prove the point, the following piece of code doesn't work. Please tell me why not.

```
package a;
public class Base
{
     protected void foo() {}
}

// in a separate file/package
package b;
public class Child extends Base
{
     private Base wrappedBase = new Base();

      @Override
      protected void foo()
      {
           wrappedBase.foo(); // <<<<< This throws "The method foo from type Base is not visible"
      }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you think `protected` would work?

Comment: Because I tried it! (Also, `protected` only makes the fields visible WITHIN the same package!)

Comment: It has to be public if you want access outside package. I would provide a getter method so you can control the access. Private variable and public get() method.

Comment: No, it absolutely does *not*. Please show what you tried - because `protected` is precisely designed to give access to subclasses. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2

Comment: Yes, it give access to subclasses IN THE SAME package.

Comment: Alright, attaching proof in the question.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html. Come on, @OneTwoThree: Jon Skeet, which has the highest rep here, tells you that protected lets you access a member from any subclass. And he provides a link to the specification. Check your facts.

Comment: I just checked the tut on it and @jon Skeet is correct that you should be able to access it in subclasses with protected.

Comment: Ok, I just attached the example. If you were right, (which you might be), could you please explain why I am getting a compile-error?

Comment: you should know that JVM will change its behaviors to comply with skeet if it has to. For more details : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Comment: @OneTwoThree your example is not accessing it's own foo method it is try to use the method of the new object you create. Try `super.foo()`

Comment: If you have parent class then why you are trying to use with Object. why don't to you use as members?

Answer (score 4):

Normaly, you would just use `protected`, which *does* work within subclasses *within the restrictions in the JLS*:

In `foo/Parent.java`:

```
package foo;

public class Parent {
    protected int x;
}
```

In `bar/Child.java`:

```
package bar;

import foo.Parent;

public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child() {
        // Look ma, access to a protected variable declared
        // by my superclass in a different package!
        x = 10;
    }
}
```

Now the example you've given is slightly different, because you're trying to access the protected variable via a compile-time type of `Base`... and *that* doesn't work. You can only access a protected member via an expression with the same compile-time type as the code doing the accessing (or a subtype). As per [section 6.2.2.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.1):

> Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.
>
> In addition, if Id denotes an instance field or instance method, then:
>
> - If the access is by a qualified name Q.Id, where Q is an ExpressionName, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of the expression Q is S or a subclass of S.
> - If the access is by a field access expression E.Id, where E is a Primary expression, or by a method invocation expression E.Id(. . .), where E is a Primary expression, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of E is S or a subclass of S.

There is no way of providing access to the protected member of *all* objects of the superclass to *all* subclasses. This is deliberate - it prevents code from creating a subclass simply in order to get access to more members of other types.

Comment: Well, that's not the case I was trying to do. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @OneTwoThree: See my updated answer. But it *is* access to a protected member outside the package, so your statement that "protected fields are ONLY VISIBLE WITHIN the same package" is incorrect.